# How to validate a non-model (and even non-object) field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation

I have a form that has a lot of fields taken from an array (not from model or object). How can I validate the presence of these fields?

```
<%= simple_form_for :solve, :url => solve_problem_path do |f| %>
  <% @input_variables.each do |label| %>
    <%= f.input label %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Validate via Javascript.

Comment: @MurifoX not good enough, what if the user has deactivated javascript or sends the request anyway ? Validation must be done server side as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a simple class to wrap the request params and use `ActiveModel::Validations`.

```
# defined somewhere, at the simplest:
require 'ostruct'

class Solve < OpenStruct
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates :foo, :bar, :presence => true    

  # you could even check the solution with a validator
  validate do
    errors.add(:base, "WRONG!!!") unless some_correct_condition
  end
end

# then in your controller
def your_method_name
  @solve = Solve.new(params[:solve])

  if @solve.valid?
    # yayyyy!
  else
    # do something with @solve.errors
  end
end
```

This gives you the benefit of validating like you would a model, complete with i18n error messages and so on.

**EDIT**: as per your comment, to validate everything you might do:

```
class Solve < OpenStruct
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  # To get the i18n to work fully you'd want to extend ActiveModel::Naming, and
  # probably define `i18n_scope`
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  validate do
    # OpenStruct maintains a hash @table of its attributes
    @table.each do |key, val|
      errors.add(key, :blank) if val.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems to be much better. But what about adding an non-empty validation for all new properties?

Comment: big yes for OpenStruct solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with attr_accessible:

```
Class YourClass < ActiveRecord::Base    
  attr_accessible :field_1
  attr_accessible :field_2

  validates :field_1, :presence => true
  validates :field_2, :presence => true
end
```

**EDIT :**

This may be a much better solution : http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/

Comment: I have array of fields and there is no previously known structure that because I can't create an ActiveModel object with validation inside.

Comment: You don't have even one active record model acting in this form? In this situation you'll have to either create one that will just act as a validation wrapper or do it on your own i guess.

Comment: Ok. I can create a model just for validation. Then I should add fields from the array into this model and set validations on those fields?

Comment: Indeed, quick & dirty way, i don't know if there is a more elegant way using the activerecord validator w/out an activerecord model though.

Comment: I have updated my post w/ a link to a better solution, give it a look

Comment: If you just meant to use custom object with ActiveModel then I have already known about it. That is not what I wanted to use.

Comment: Well if you want active record errors handling i'm affraid you don't have a lot of solutions ...